# Svelte: Child method Ondestroy() doesn't invoke after removing of a parent component

Tags: svelte

Why doesn't child method Ondestroy() invoke after removing of a parent component from DOM?

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/46cf5d5b369a4499b804147ae88eea96?version=3.49.0)

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Child from "./child.svelte";
    let compRef;
</script>

<button on:click={() => compRef.parentNode.removeChild(compRef)}>remove</button> 

<div bind:this={compRef}>
    <Child />
    <Child />
    <Child />
</div>
```

Child.svelte

```
<script>
    import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte";
    onDestroy(()=> console.log("Child was destroyed!"))
</script>

<h1>
    Child
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `comRef` holds a reference to the `div` element, that's not a component
2. Manipulating the DOM directly in Svelte is usually not a good idea. If you want to remove the elements from the DOM either wrap them in an `{#if}` block and set the condition to `false`
   [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c798dfa566434896bdcb0af742317142?version=3.49.0)

```
<script>
    import Child from "./child.svelte";
    let condition = true;
</script>

<button on:click={() => condition = false}>remove</button> 

{#if condition}
<div>
    <Child />
    <Child />
    <Child />
</div>
{/if}
```

or, if the wrapper was a component, it could alternatively also be done by calling `.$destroy()`
[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a6931c71b3a245e0a80873ad24f962f7?version=3.49.0)

```
<script>
    import Child from "./Child.svelte";
    import Parent from "./Parent.svelte";
    let compRef
</script>

<button on:click={() => compRef.$destroy()}>remove</button> 

<Parent bind:this={compRef}>
    <Child />
    <Child />
    <Child />
</Parent>
```

Check the console to see, that in both cases the `onDestroy` callback will run

Comment: @ariman Great :) If your question got answered it's best you mark is so by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the most helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

`onDestroy` has nothing to do with whether the element is in the DOM. Components can also have no elements at all.

The callback is for cleaning up any event listeners and other things *not* managed by Svelte. The function will be called automatically if Svelte removes a component. If you instantiated a component, you have to call `$destroy` manually.

Your example looks like a case for using a simple `{#if}`, that way Svelte will destroy the component when the condition is `false`.